# Editing fid to match row number using QGIS?

Tags: qgis, attribute-table

[image]

Tried editing it but it wont allow to save the edit.

Answer (score 2):

In a table there are no row numbers as in a spreadsheet.

However, there is a field that unequivocally identifies each feature by assigning a number, to meet performance and integrity (data and referential) requirements. That field is usually called *fid*. Nothing ensures, if it is not specified in the query to the table, the order that the rows of a table should take when they are shown.

In the Qgis table editor, that kind of spreedsheet row numbers are shown only for convenience, perhaps to keep a visible account of the features.

Answer (score 0):

Got it. I just added a new column and removed the fid column via right-clicking the column header > Organize Columns > Unclick fid

Comment: That simply hides the column, it does not delete it.